# Wordpress 1 domain multiple blogs

Tags: categories

I need to setup a website with wordpress that 1 domain with have different pages of blogs. For example: 
- my website have Home, Artworks, Techniques pages. 
- Artworks and Techniques are 2 different blogs. 
- Home will shows whichever posts that is latest from Artwork and Techniques.

How can I do that with wordpress?? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Just use different categories and link your "blog" to the category page.

Answer (score 2):

Your answer was solved many years ago then not long ago integrated into the current version of WordPress:  MU then Network/MultiSite.  You can read about creating a network at the [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network)

Comment: Can you get two different blogs to both appear on the Home page?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly you just want to sort things into categories.

If you want to make completely separate sites you can install WordPress into different directories and run them as subdomains.

Answer (score 0):

Use 'categories' to sort between the posts you have for the 2 blogs (Artworks and Techniques). 
Then use this code snippet on your homepage to spit out posts in a category.:

```
<?php
query_posts(’showposts=1&cat=3′);
while(have_posts()) : the_post();
?>
<ul><li>
<h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title();
?></a></h3>
<ul><li><?php the_content_limit(520); ?></li>
</ul></li></ul>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Hopefully, it'll work for you.